# Literature on the time reversal operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, time-reversal-symmetry

[Time reversal symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry) seems to be a very useful concept and is mentioned in a good number of papers I recently came across. Most of the time people claim that a certain system or Hamiltonian is time reversal invariant and deduce certain properties without going further into details.

I have a hard time grasping the entire time reversal symmetry thing and would like to read more on the subject in general. So I was wondering whether anybody had good literature references? Preferably with a lot of applications and examples. I know the mathematical definition, but its applications usually elude me.